# Package `listings`: add counter to custom-defined language

Tags: listings, algorithms, julia

I am using the `listings` package to include some [Julia](https://julialang.org/) code, however the Julia language is not yet supported by the `listings` package. As a result I had to make my own (basic) set of rules, inspired by several sources, using `\lstdefinelanguage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% JULIA ALGORITHM STYLING
\lstdefinelanguage{Julia}%
  {morekeywords={abstract,break,case,catch,const,continue,do,else,elseif,%
      end,export,false,for,function,immutable,import,importall,if,in,%
      macro,module,otherwise,quote,return,switch,true,try,type,typealias,%
      using,while},%
   sensitive=true,%
   alsoother={\$},%
   morecomment=[l]{\#},%
   morecomment=[n]{\#=}{=\#},%
   morestring=[s]{"}{"},%
   morestring=[m]{'}{'},%
}[keywords,comments,strings]%

\lstset{%
    language            = Julia,
    basicstyle          = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle        = \bfseries\color{blue},
    stringstyle         = \color{purple},
    commentstyle        = \color{teal},
    showstringspaces    = false,
    numbers             = left,
    breaklines          = true,
    breakatwhitespace   = false,
    basicstyle          = \footnotesize
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=Julia, title=A beautiful Julia algorithm, label=mycode]{/path/to/a/julia/file.jl}\
\end{document}
```

I want to add a counter to my listings (right now it doesn't appear).

So I would like the captions of my listings to look like

`Listing 1: A beautiful Julia algorithm`

But now it looks like this

[image: Current output]

*NB: I did my research but couldn't find an answer that worked for me.*

#### Edit

- Following @Mensch 's comment, I modified the code snippet above to make it a compilable minimal working example.
  `file.jl` is simply any julia file. I made sure that my julia file
  is compilable and it is properly included in my LaTeX file using the above code snippet with the right path.
- I included a screenshot of the current output

Comment: Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

Comment: There you go. Do you need anything else @Mensch ?

Comment: Did you try `caption=A beautiful Julia algorithm` instead of `title=`?

Comment: It worked, thanks ! I posted an answer with your solution. If you prefer to post the answer yourself, just post it and I will remove mine, as well as accepting yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Marijn's comment, the answer was actually very simple.

Instead of `title=A beautiful Julia algorithm`

Write `caption=A beautiful Julia algorithm`.

This creates a counter and adds it in front of the caption, as follows:
[image: Valid result]

Thanks again @Marijn !